# Is there a way to load images but hide them from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, next.js

I'm building a memory game in React et Next.js, I'm using the pokeapi to load pokemon data like pokemon name, image etc.

I want to preload images from the pokeapi but hide them in the DOM to avoid malicious users inspecting the HTML.

If I show the card conditionally like this:

```
          {isSwitchedCard && (
            <NextImage
              src={card.image}
              width={150}
              height={150}
              alt={card.name}
              draggable={false}
              className="m-5 rounded-t-lg"
            />
          )}
```

the image load when the user click on it and it could take too much time for certain users with bad network.

So I search for a solution to preload images from API but hide them from the DOM, any ideas?

Comment: Please explain the meaning of "hide them in the DOM to avoid malicious users inspecting the HTML".

Comment: Even if you "download" the images to the browser but not display them, a "cheater" gamer can still inspect the network tab and view the images there.

Comment: @AchiPapakon, yes, but he can't know where each image is positioned in the memory card game because I randomized cards placement

Comment: @Yogi, it means I don't want <img> tag in the HTML, because cheaters can open the browser dev tool and inspect the HTML to see where images are positioned

Comment: @Flosrn why you would have <img> with the source that you want to hide in the first place? You should display something else and when the user clicks, just replace that something else with the src that you want using javascript.

Comment: @AchiPapakon because if I do that, the image load when the user clicks on it and it could take too much time for certain users with a bad network.

Comment: @Flosrn you are confusing React, JavaScript and HTML. There's no need to load the images with <src>. You can explicitly load how many images you want in the beginning of your application using javascript.

Comment: @AchiPapakon? I think you don't understand. Do the test on your side, even if you load images at the beginning with js, if you want to initially hide the image (with conditional rendering, as I said, to prevent cheaters), when you click on the image, it will take some time on a slow network.